# Add string of dates to qml calendar

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, calendar, qml, qtquick2

**UPDATED AFTER ADJUSTMENTS**

So after amending my code from the suggestions and working with the visibility of my image and pushing the dates to an array I am still not seeing the individually marked dates, my new code is:

```
    property var arrayFromFirebase: []

onFirebaseReady: {
          firebaseDb.getUserValue("dates", {
                                      orderByChild: true
                        }, function(success, key, value) {
                                  if(success) {
                                      console.log(JSON.stringify(value))
                                for( date in value){arrayFromFirebase.push(date.date)}
                                      }
                              })
      }

Image {
       visible: arrayFromFirebase.indexOf(styleData.date.getDate()) > -1
       }
```

My log still reads the arrayFromFirebase in the format of:

```
[{"date":"2018-10-01T21:17:00.926"},{"date":"2018-10-02T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-03T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-06T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-07T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-08T12:00:00.000"}]
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have my a calendar which my users save selected dates which are stored in firebase, my calendar is built with example in the link

[QtQuick Calendar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-calendar-example.html)

My user dates are stored to firebase, and when i read them i can receive them in the log using JSON.stringify,

When writing the saved dates to my database I use the following code:

```
    property var userData: {      
  "selectedDates": [         
        { },
      ]
}

  AppButton {
      id: saveButton
      text: "Save & Request"
      anchors.right: parent.right
      textColor: "#4e4e4e"
      backgroundColor: "#d1d1d1"
      onClicked: {
        userData.selectedDates.push({ "date": calendar.selectedDate});
        console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));
        firebaseDb.setUserValue("dates", userData.selectedDates)
      }
  }
```

Then when reading the dates I use the following:

```
  FirebaseDatabase {
      config: customConfig
      onFirebaseReady: {
          firebaseDb.getUserValue("dates", {
                                      startAt: {
                                          Key: "1/date",
                                      }
                        }, function(success, key, value) {
                                  if(success) {
                                      console.log(JSON.stringify(value))
                                      }
                              })
      }
  }
```

Once this is read the log displays the dates as follows:

```
[{"date":"2018-10-01T21:17:00.926"},{"date":"2018-10-02T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-03T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-06T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-07T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-08T12:00:00.000"}]
```

I want to take this string of dates and add markers to my calendar to show they are booked?

How would I go about this?

The Type `FirebaseDatabase` is documented [**here**](https://v-play.net/doc/vplayplugins-firebasedatabase/)

**CALENDAR QML CODE**

[CalendarQMLCode](http://pastebin.com/W0ZQFRBe)

Comment: To improve your question, please provide some code. I don't know firebase, but I might help you with QML. For me it would be helpful, to know in which form you read the data from the firebase - how do you have it in QML. The code should also show some attempt you try to solve this.

Comment: @derM Hello, Thanks for the quick reply! I have updated the original post including code of how i read/write to my firebase database, does this give you a better idea of what i would need to to? Thanks Again!

Comment: You should format the dates you've received from the database. Then you either should convert the string to `date` type. (from the Qt docs: _to create a date value, specify it as a "YYYY-MM-DD" string_) or parse the string using Javascript `Date.parse()`

Comment: Hi @folibis this is unfortunately where I am struggling, taking my string of dates and formatting them to then use! sorry if my question wasn't entirely clear in that I tried to make it so, even when reading through the docs and trying several variations it's taking the 'value' which I read from firebase and formatting to add to my calendar!

Comment: I don't know Firebase at all but I've used different databases a lot and all of them have options to format the output. I would think again before using a tool that doesn't allow that.

Comment: why not use `SqlEventModel` (**sqlite**) as done in the link you cited [Qt Quick Calendar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-calendar-example.html)  ? when you read your data from firebase store/insert it in `SqlEventModel` locally !!!

Comment: Hey!! @Redanium that sounds like a viable option which I have thought of! Would i need to set up a seperate SQL database for this though? As i have no idea how i would insert it into the SqlEventModel but will try playing around this evening! I assume i would  need to seperate my JSON string of dates i have called to then add as individual events (my current struggle in all approaches) thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Ldweller follow the **Qt Quick Controls - Calendar Example**
 with some tweaking of the  C++ class, `SqlEventModel`, you'll achieve what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Hey @Redanium Once again thanks for the responses you've really helped out! So after working to implement the SqlEventModel into my app I started a new project, and copy/paste all .cpp/.h/.qml with the exact same names and get an error due to a module not being installed: **module "org.qtproject.examples.calendar" is not installed** which is on the main .qml. I can see this is an old example link but without this I error with **SqlEventModel is not a type** from the main.qml what would replace this module to work instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a development holiday, I have a working solution! So see below (excluding all excess code) and thanks to everyone for your help!! (especially @Redanium for your patience)

```
Main.qml:
App {

    property var arrayFromFireBase: []

 onLoggedIn:  {
      firebaseDb.getUserValue("dates/selectedDates", {},
                                    function(success, key, value) {
                                    if(success) {
                                         for(var idx in value)
                                            arrayFromFireBase.push(new Date(value[idx].date).getTime())
                                    })}}
```

Then on my calendar page the following:

```
CalendarPage.qml:

Page {
AppButton {
          id: saveButton
          text: "Save & Request"
              onClicked: {
                  userData.selectedDates.push({"date": calendar.selectedDate});
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));
                  firebaseDb.setUserValue("dates", userData)
                  }
           }

property var userData: { 
            "selectedDates": [{}]
           }

Image {
       visible: arrayFromFireBase.indexOf(styleData.date.getTime()) > -1
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** (after @derM comment)

No need to use sqlite DB model

Just in the `dayDelegate` we play with *the event indicator image* `visibility`

For that after getting your data from firebase, save it to an array (we name it `arrayFromFireBase`)  and check if `styleData.date` is in that array

```
FirebaseDatabase {
  config: customConfig
  onFirebaseReady: {
      firebaseDb.getUserValue("dates", {
                                  startAt: {
                                      Key: "1/date",
                                  }
                    }, function(success, key, value) {
                              if(success) {
                                  console.log(JSON.stringify(value))
                                  // value here is JSON ARRAY
                                  // value =[{"date":"2018-10-01T21:17:00.926"},{"date":"2018-10-02T12:00:00.000"}]
                                  // so value[0].date ="2018-10-01T21:17:00.926"
                                  //then you gonna insert here your dates in arrayFromFireBase as strings as follow
                                  for(i=0 ; i < arrayFromFireBase.length-1 ; i++) 
                                    arrayFromFireBase.push(new Date(value[i].date).getTime())
                                  }
                          })
  }
}
Calendar {
    ...
    style: CalendarStyle {
        dayDelegate: Item {
            ...
            Image {
                // HERE WE MUST COMPARE TIME (we used Date.getTime()) FROM FIREBASE with the calendar's date converted to time also 
                visible: arrayFromFireBase.indexOf(styleData.date.getTime()) > -1
                ...
                source: "qrc:/images/eventindicator.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

---

Part of the code was taken from [Qt Quick Controls - Calendar Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-calendar-example.html)

Just added `void SqlEventModel::insertDates(QStringList dates)`

**C++ part**

```
SqlEventModel::SqlEventModel()
{
 createConnection();
}

void SqlEventModel::createConnection()
{
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
 db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
 if (!db.open()) {
     qFatal("Cannot open database");
     return;
 }
}
void SqlEventModel::insertDates(QStringList dates){
 QSqlQuery query;
 // We store the time as seconds because it's easier to query.
 // It depends on what you want as columns for your events
 query.exec("create table Event (name TEXT, startDate DATE, startTime INT, 
  endDate DATE, endTime INT)");
 foreach(QString date in dates){

  // It depends on what you want as columns for your events
  query.exec(QString("insert into Event values('%1', '%2', 
  %3, '%4', %5)").arg(date[0]).arg(date[1]).arg(date[2]).arg(date[3]).arg(date[4]));
 }
 return;
}
```

**QML part**

```
SqlEventModel {
 id: eventModel
}

FirebaseDatabase {
  config: customConfig
  onFirebaseReady: {
      firebaseDb.getUserValue("dates", {
                                  startAt: {
                                      Key: "1/date",
                                  }
                    }, function(success, key, value) {
                              if(success) {
                                  console.log(JSON.stringify(value))
                                  //Insert here your dates in sql model
                                  eventModel.insertDates(value)
                                  }
                          })
  }
}
```

Comment: So you propose, putting stuff that you receive from a DB into a SQLITE DB just to provide a model? Isn't that a bit of overkill?

Comment: You are right, we can do it without sqlite DB. My answer was based on the fact that he used [Qt Quick Controls - Calendar Example
](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-calendar-example.html)

Comment: @derM - I had tried working with the visibility before but as a property bool rather than array! After implementing your suggestions I am still not viewing the marker on saved days? I have updated my original question with my new code since your comments! Also thank you so so much with the help!

Comment: Hi @Redanium I understand that if the cell date matches the array is true/false, but is my code of `arrayFromFirebase.push(JSON.stringify(value))` to place the data in the array and `property var arrayFromFirebase: []` not correct then as it is not working? i'm sorry to frustrate you all!

Comment: check your updated question and check the `arrayFromFirebase`'s **length**

Comment: @Redanium Sorry, I am new to this, even with your code edits added I still cannot get this working - I have been reading about my array length yet have either continued with no markers or markers on every day on the Calendar - I will read further and hopefully get this working. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ldweller  :) no worries Bro we are here to help each other and learn from our mistakes. Just updated my answer if you would check it .

Comment: @Redanium Thanks again for the adjustment, have been working with and tweaking all night but am yet to yield success but will continue looking into the cause of it not working properly. Thanks

Comment: @Ldweller At least tell us what you are getting as output

Comment: @Redanium Using the above changes you have made, with `property var arrayFromFireBase: []` my log output is **[{"date":"2018-10-07T21:52:47.323"},{"date":"2018-10-01T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-02T12:00:00.000"},{"date":"2018-10-08T12:00:00.000"}]
Read Value: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] for key: dates** 

due to the nested values of my database the [object Object] is caused for each date read from firebase, the JSON.stringify changes that back to the {"date": "2018-10-8" you see, yet no image is visible on the calendar. sorry for the trouble

Comment: @Ldweller the output you are getting is from `console.log(JSON.stringify(value))` ... what is the output of `console.log(arrayFromFireBase)` ?

Comment: @Ldweller You won't get an image on the calendar because **1.** It's not part of the calendar's `dayDelegate` and **2.** You have to specify a source for it (the image)...Where is your calendar qml code ???

Comment: @Redanium oh Jesus, so when I add `console.log(arrayFromFireBase)` directly after my log of the stringify log I get a blank entry, I have moved my `property var arrayFromFireBase: []` into the `dayDelegate: Item {…..}` area and no change, my image has is sourced in the `"../assets/logo.png"` which I has loaded onto all dates on a failed attempt, or is this not what you mean by specifying the source for it?

Thanks!

Comment: `arrayFromFireBase` must be declared on top of the file so it can be accessible from other components and you must log it content after the `for` **loop** (after elements got pushed to it )

Comment: @Redanium I have kept the `arrayFromFireBase` at the top of the file until my previous comment of moving it into the day delegate, I have now moved it into the root of `main.qml` I have also tried moving the log to after the `for` loop and I get no output from it at all? so my code looks like `for(i=0 ; i < arrayFromFireBase.length-1; i++) {
                                          arrayFromFireBase.push(new Date(value[i].date).getTime())}
                                          console.log("ARRAYLOG  " + arrayFromFireBase)` Is this what you mean by that?

Comment: @Redanium I see you have also asked where my calendar qml code is, I will update the question with this now removing as much excess as I can

Comment: After a couple of days tweaking, I am at the following:
due to my database structure, my initial read value is `[[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]]` then if I apply `console.log(JSON.stringify(value))` my log output is the dates I have saved. and when adding `.length` to the log I get the number of saved dates. but if I run `var callDate
callDate = JSON.stringify(value)` and log `callDate.length` the output is the number of characters (106 in this example) alternate methods have resulted in my output returning to `[object Object]` @Redanium what do you suggest? Thanks again

Comment: @Ldweller If it possible to get your source code , it'll be much better (paste it to PASTEBIN.COM) and post the link

Comment: @Redanium i will do this tonight when able to access my pc! Would you want just the calendar page or full app source code?

Comment: @Ldweller just calendar qml page

Comment: @Redanium Hey, i remembered i had a backup on my external hdd, please see link; https://pastebin.com/W0ZQFRBe